# Error: The Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) when using proxy

Tags: visual-studio-2012, proxy, remote-debugging, windows

First of all I changed Visual Studio 2012 `.Net Framework 4.5` to `.Net Framework 4 Client Profile` in my project.
also I'm using **https proxy** with third party application -> [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/)
after that when I want to start the application I got this error :

[image]

**ERROR :**

`The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not apear to be running on the remote computer ...`

What this error mean and how can I remove it?
**Note :** In visual studio 2010 I don't have such that error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing **properties/compile/target** platform to **x86** instead of Any CPU. It solved the problem in my case. Hope it helps.